# Removing AX88179 Driver

Tags: drivers, ethernet

Hi I have issued the following command to install the  ASIX AX88179 driver  :

sudo make install

su -c "cp -v ax88179_178a.ko /lib/modules/3.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb && /sbin/depmod -a"
`ax88179_178a.ko' ->`/lib/modules/3.8.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko'

But the driver does not work as intended. How can I revert these changes ?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Perhaps we can help you make it work as intended. What doesn't work? Where did you get the driver? May we have a link?

Comment: Hi I used the manufactures site. http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE.tar.bz2

There is a readme in there. It mentions that I need the Linux sources in order to install. I will try again once i have them.

Comment: In Ubuntu talk, that means linux-headers. You wouldn't have gotten the driver built without massive errors without headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to build this driver is, with a working internet connection:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
cd ~/Desktop/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE
```

...or wherever you extracted the package, if not desktop.

```
make
```

The driver ax88179_178a is present in Ubuntu 13.10, so if you re-install, compiling will be unnecessary.

Most Makefiles have a process to make, clean, install and uninstall. Yours evidently does not. First, let's test the driver to see if it drives the device correctly:

```
cd ~/Desktop/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE
sudo modprobe usbnet
sudo insmod ax88179_178a.ko
```

Does your device work correctly? If so, we'll install it the hard way:

```
sudo cp ax88179_178a.ko  /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/usb/
```

Those backticks are on the left side of my US keyboard on the same key with ~. This will overwrite your previous attempt, if any.

It seems that your device connects and immediately drops. I noticed this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1269883 Evidently, the poster had better luck with a USB 2.0 port. Please try.

Aside from that, I suggest you contact ASIX, as they are the author of the driver we compiled.

Comment: I downloaded the headers, make, make install but received a STOP error:

kam270@dan:~/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE$ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-37-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/kam270/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-37-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-37-generic'
kam270@dan:~/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE$ sudo make installl
make: *** No rule to make target `installl'.  Stop.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: when i ty inserting the module I get another error

kam270@dan:~/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE$ sudo insmod ax88179_178a.ko
insmod: error inserting 'ax88179_178a.ko': -1 Unknown symbol in module

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: I tried edited version above but get this:
kam270@dan:~/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE$ sudo modprobe usbnet
[sudo] password for kam270: 
kam270@dan:~/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE$ sudo insmod ax88179_178a.ko
insmod: error inserting 'ax88179_178a.ko': -1 File exists
kam270@dan:~/Downloads/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.9.0_SOURCE$

Comment: 'File exists' sounds like the driver is already loaded; check: lsmod. Also check: dmesg | grep ax88

Comment: lsmod

usbnet                 32002  1 ax88179_178a 

dmesg | grep ax88 
[21777.221535] ax88179_178a 4-2:1.0 (unregistered net_device): mtu 1500
[21777.221842] ax88179_178a 4-2:1.0 eth1: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 80:3f:5d:09:3d:4f
[21777.222886] usbcore: registered new interface driver ax88179_178a

Comment: The above seems to indicate the driver is now loaded. However I can not get out. Can not ping anything. There are flashing lights on the adapter though but they go off after about 30secs.

Comment: Looks promising. Does Network Manager see the connection or what? Is there any clue at: cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e eth1 -e etwork. Please use: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7192888/

Comment: After failure and cable disconnected : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7192893/

Comment: Network manager does see the connection but after 30 seconds I loose connection.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I did try contacting them but their support form  does not work and no email or contact no. Looks like a dodgy Chinese set up.

Thanks for taking the time to assist. Much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you try the live USB or DVD for 13.10 or 14.04 and see if the included driver works.